# how to create dynamic columns in a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, dynamic

I have a query, could you please tell me.

- Is there any possibility to create a dynamic columns in MySQL?
- Is there any way to create a columns at the time of
  querying(inserting, updating)?
- Is there any way to create columns, just like creating rows at the
  time row insertion.

Comment: you should have a look at some nosql engine. http://nosql-database.org/

Comment: If you want Schema to be changing dynamically then why don't you use MongoDB? You can add new columns using DDL statements through any programming language at run time when ever you require.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "dynamic" columns?

Comment: @neville K , i mean adding columns dynamically ,

Comment: @shubhansh , i had almost developed the schema in mysql , so now i cant migrate to mongodb, so kindly request that tell me , if there is a way in mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column to a table by using the `ALTER TABLE` [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html); add a column while you are doing an `INSERT` doesn't sound feasible to me, and even if it's possible I would descourage it. You should know which columns you are inserting values in *before* running the `INSERT` statement. My choice would be to `ALTER` your table before the `INSERT` statement.

That said, why are you needing this? I sense a disturbance in your database design, if you really need to add columns dynamically :)